# Have one button go to a different view and enable button

Tags: ios

I am working on an app where I have multiple buttons on one page that you click on to go to a different view. The thing is I would like the user to click on them in a specific order. So basically, have all buttons locked except for one and then each time you click on a button that is enabled, it unlocks a new one.

Thanks.

Comment: What problems did you encounter when you tried to implement this?

Comment: Well what happened was, when I clicked on the button my app just crashed.

Comment: Post relevant code and details about the crash (like the full error message).

Comment: I tried the answer but it didn't work because every time I went back to the view with the buttons my button was still disabled. Does anyone know what to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily via `Tag`

When you creating view at that time just put `FirstButton` in `Enabled` mode.

`OnClick` event on every `UIButton` you can `Enabled` next one.

For example

i created `View` with 4 `UIButton` and given tag `1,2,3,4` at `ViewLoad` only `UIButton` with `Tag` 1 is only `Enabled`

For all 4 `UIButton` i have created common `Action` method as follow which `Enabled` next `UIButton` with next `Tag`

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"LastEnableButton"]){

        UIButton * btnTemp = (UIButton *) [self.view viewWithTag:[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"LastEnableButton"] intValue]];
        [btnTemp setEnabled:YES];

        NSLog(@"If you want to enable all button which are enabled previously then make for loop up to NSUserDefaults value from starting value");
    }
}

- (IBAction)btn_click : (id)sender {

    UIButton * btnTemp = (UIButton *) [self.view viewWithTag:([sender tag] + 1)];
    if(btnTemp) {
        if([btnTemp isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            [btnTemp setEnabled:YES];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:([sender tag] + 1)] forKey:@"LastEnableButton"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I tried this but it didn't quite work like I wanted it to. The button1 did enable button 2 and go to a new view controller(because when I clicked on button 1 button 2 was blue for a split second. but when I went back to the view controller with all the buttons, button 2 was disabled. What do I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Do one thing you can store `Enable` button tag in `NSUserDefaults` when you `click` on any `button` And in `ViewWillApper` method you can set `Enable = TRUE to button`after coming back to same `ViewController`. Just you have to find button with `viewWithTag` method and need `enable` it.

Comment: The problem I have is that I don't know how to do that. Where is ViewWillAppear?